# Windows.Foundation.Uri supports Data URI Scheme?

Tags: windows-runtime, winjs

Does Windows.Foundation.Uri supports [data URI Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), if yes, can I use that in Windows.UI.StartScreen.SecondaryTile as logoReference parameter? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested this using the JavaScript Grid app template, and it does not work.

The constructor for Windows.Foundation.Uri will happily accept a data URI, but the constructor for Windows.UI.StartScreen.SecondaryTile throws an exception when attempting to initialize the tile with the data URI.

So you will probably need to find another way of solving this. Perhaps you can dynamically create the tile image and save it to your appdata folder, which can then be accessed via the ms-appdata:// URI scheme?

For more info on Windows Store app development, register for [Generation App](http://bit.ly/gd30tolaunch).